# Android: Passing Int with Intent crashing app

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, int

Hi hoping someone can help me with a error i'm getting when running my code. What want is when the user gets game over the score from the main class is taken to the gameover class to display the final score. without the intent the game over screen loads fine but when I add the intent upon gameover running the game the app crashes Here is my code where score is the int:

main class intent:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,gameover.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("number", score);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

gameover class:

```
EndScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);

            int numScore;
            numScore = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");
            String s = String.valueOf( numScore );
            EndScore.setText(s);
```

I have been looking around the forums but can't see what I am doing wrong.
Log is as follows:

```
12-28 02:36:37.760: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(17096): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-28 02:36:37.770: D/memalloc(17096): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5189a000 size:4866048 offset:4251648 fd:68
12-28 02:36:37.860: D/memalloc(17096): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51e6e000 size:2949120 offset:2334720 fd:71
12-28 02:36:38.870: W/dalvikvm(17096): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b0a9f0)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phil3992.colourguess/com.phil3992.colourguess.gameover}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at com.phil3992.colourguess.gameover.onCreate(gameover.java:22)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-28 02:36:38.880: E/AndroidRuntime(17096):    ... 11 more
```

The int is  increment when the user scores a point then on game over it should send and be shown in the textview

Update whole gameover class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class gameover extends Activity {
    Button re_run;
    TextView EndScore;
      @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
          re_run = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
            setContentView(R.layout.gameover);
           EndScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);

        int numScore;
        numScore = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");
        String s = String.valueOf( numScore );
        EndScore.setText(s);

      }
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setButtonOnClickListeners(){

            re_run.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
    }

      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          // Do nothing
      }
    }
```

Comment: what is type of score u passing and post logs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: post the whole `gameover` class

Comment: As suggested by @DIVA, provide the Logcat and we can probably aide.

Comment: Post The whole gameover.class if you can.

Comment: You have a NPE at line 22 of your class. See for yourself, should be easy to solve. It's much more important that you tell which line is line 22 than your whole class, actually.

Comment: @Phil3992 That wouldn't make sense.  That would have to be from another iteration.  If the line number doesn't match up with the code, perhaps you could say which line it does match up with.  You can't have a null pointer on a line for initializing a primitive integer.

Comment: I didn't think it seemed correct saying there was an error with the int. could it have wanted line 23, being:

numScore = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this line-

```
   re_run = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry);
```

Below

```
setContentView().
```

Comment: Try using Bundle to send the score, if you think error is due to putExtras();

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the `TextView EndScore` (if you could in the future use lower case letters for variables) could not be found within the `R.layout.gameover` layout.

Be sure that the TextView is actually in that XML file.
Be sure that it is a `TextView` and not something else, like an `EditText` or something similar (although I think that would throw a different error).

`EndScore` is null according to the LogCat.

Comment: text view is definitely in the xml:

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/KO"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:text="@string/end" />